# Execute a method depending on user input without if/else

Tags: angular, typescript

Depending on the user input ("0", "1", "2") I want to execute a method. What is a good way to do it without

```
if(input == "0")
  methodA();
else if(input == "1")
  methodB();
etc..
```

I rather want to fill a map or something equal like this:

```
"0" -> methodA()
"1" -> methodB()
"2" -> methodC()
```

find user input in map and execute the corresponding method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have something like this:

```
 methodA = function () {
    Console.log("A");
 }; 
 methodB = function () {
    Console.log("B");
 };
 methodC = function () {
    Console.log("C");
 };
   
 inpResonse = {
    "0": this.methodA,
    "1": this.methodB,
    "2": this.methodC
 };
```

and then invoke `(inpResponse[input])()`

Comment: What's with `this` here?  The question didn't use `this` when calling the methods, and if you do need a `this` context, then `(inpResponse[input])()` will not have the desired effect.

Comment: I forgot "this". thanks for the answer. Would it be better to use an interface?

Comment: @NoobieNoob - it depends on the bigger picture. You didn't put a "big picture" (Component, interface) to make such decision

Answer (score 0):

```js
const methods = {
  '0': x => console.log(`method A your input value was ${x}`),
  '1': x => console.log(`method B your input value was ${x}`)  
}

methods['0'](5)
methods['1'](3)
```